# Cannot set NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey property

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to set attribute `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` but I get exception of folder(or file, if I try to do this with each file separately) is not found.

code is following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
    documentsRoot = documentsDirectory! + "/"

    var root = NSURL(string: documentsRoot!)

    addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(root!)
}

func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL: NSURL) -> Void {

    var filepath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(URL)")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.absoluteString))

    var error:NSError?

    do {
        try filepath.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error excluding \(filepath.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
    }

    return
}
```

when I run the code I get this output

> Error excluding Optional(" ... cuments") from backup Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “ ... cuments” doesn’t
>   exist."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D1FC9BFB-4F95-440D-A3C5-ED1C0665A610/data/Containers/Data/Application/%20...%20cuments/, NSFilePath=/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D1FC9BFB-4F95-440D-A3C5-ED1C0665A610/data/Containers/Data/Application/
>   ... cuments, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f86b2c80850 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

What Im I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the text description of the URL here:

```
var filepath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(URL)") // \(URL) is a string that contains not just the path, but also the optionality of the variable
```

whereas you should use the [path](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/path) property on NSURL.